# How to install a second version of Audacity?

Tags: software-installation

I'm running the most recent version of Audacity, 1.3.12.

I'd like to install a second version (1.2.6) because there's a filter I'd like access to that only exists in that version. (As I'm only installing it for this reason, my 1.3.12 install needs to stay untouched.)

As a recent convert from Windows XP, I'm still a bit fuzzy on how Ubuntu deals with installing files. Can I just use the deb file from [this page](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/linux)?

Or will it muck up my current 1.3.12 installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing a new version from a regular Ubuntu/Debian package will overwrite your current version. Ubuntu's package management does not support installing multiple versions of the same package.

Your option is to build from source and specify a different install dir, check the following instructions:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

On your case during the source configure phase you will need to use:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/audacious1.2.6
```

This will make sure the files will be installed into /opt/audacious1.2.6 .

Comment: yep...opt and manual compilation are your friends...of course you may find yourself in dependency hell when trying to get older software to work

Answer (score 2):

Even if you get it working at all, Audacity 1.2.6 does not run well on modern versions of Ubuntu.

Multiple versions of Audacity can be installed if built from the source code by setting a different installation location when running configure. For example, to set the installation location to your home directory, use:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

A simpler method is to not actually install the second version but just to build it within a folder. The second version can then be launched by either typing the full path to the executable in the command line, or by opening a Terminal window, navigating to the folder where you have built the second version, and then typing:

```
./audacity
```

However, I would recommend against trying to install Audacity 1.2.6 at all.
If your only reason for installing is to run a particular "filter", then the same, or an improved version of that filter is almost certainly available for Audacity 1.3.12. Unfortunately I cannot give any more information about this aspect as you have not said what this particular "filter" is.

If you are unable to find information about particular Audacity filters here on AskUbuntu I would recommend that you ask on the [Audacity forum](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewforum.php?f=18).

Answer (score 0):

well also... if you're willing to run 1.3.9 instead of 1.3.12 for your current version, you could install the old version the old fashion way... then run the portable appimage of 1.3.9 audacity which can be found at portablelinuxapps.org.

these work sort of similar to mac's .app files, it's a whole program in one file.

2 notes

1) this isn't an officially supported ubuntu method, but it is cool and it may help your problem...

2) appimages from portablelinuxapps.org  are only for 32 bit. The people in charge of portablelinux apps are very stubborn about 64 bit support. They tell poeple that using 64 bit linux is not a good experience and that it will cause problems, which is completely ignorant. In my opinion that kind of attitude is whats holding the project and it's credibility back. it's a good solution, but it needs to support both sides of the coin. i personally think the guy behind "RUNZ" appimages at hacktolive.org has a much better approach but there aren't many packages available. I just wish the portable linux app people would get their head out of the rock it's under and realize that 64 bit is important to a whole lot of people considering it's the current standard technology.